# Caffe: Why in Imagenet model activation dimension of fc6 is 4096?

Tags: caffe, activation, conv-neural-network, imagenet

I was looking at pool5 layer in the Imagenet trained model (ILSVRC challenge) whose output size is 256*6*6 (~9000), after which there is a fc6 layer whose num_outputs is 4096. Can anyone please explain how is 4096 chosen?

Comment: CNN tutorials that help: [UFLDL Tutorial](http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/tutorial/) and [CS231n](http://cs231n.github.io/)

Comment: num of output is arbitrary. It is part of the design considerations of the net.

Comment: @Shai Can you please explain what do you mean by design considerations?

Comment: @Deven I'm afraid this is too broad